# C# ASP.NET How to change datagrid header text based on item value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid would like to change the header text of the column based on the value of a cell. How to get the header of the cell and change the text?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Datagrid html below:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlWarrant" runat="server" Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="dlWarrant_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Table runat="server" ID="resulttable" Width="100%" >
        <asp:TableRow>
          <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlign="left">
             <asp:DataGrid CellSpacing="1" runat="server" ID="dgWarrant1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%"
                DataSource='<%# Eval("DETAILS1") %>' Font-Size="8.5pt" OnItemDataBound="dgWarrant1_OnItemDataBound">
             <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
             <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
             <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Mode="NumericPages" CssClass="PagerStyle" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" />
             <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PA_NO" HeaderText="WARRANT NO." HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TOTAL_UNITS_HELD" HeaderText="NO. OF UNITS HELD" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="YR_ENDED" HeaderText="YEAR ENDING" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUT" HeaderText="TYPE OF DISTRIBUTION" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TRANS_DATE" HeaderText="REINVESTMENT DATE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="INCOME_TREATMENT" HeaderText="INCOME_TREATMENT" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" />
             </Columns>
           </asp:DataGrid>
         </asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>
     </asp:Table>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

My code-behind:

```
protected void dgWarrant1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // if INCOME_TREATMENT <> R
            if (e.Item.Cells[5].Text != "R")
            {
                //change the header of Cells[4] to DISTRIBUTION DATE
            }
            else
            {
                //change the header of Cells[4] to REINVESTMENT DATE
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: since `DataGrid` whose items get bound is in `DataList` control, you must first get reference to your grid control. You can to it like this:

```
//get grid as Item's parent
DataGrid grid = e.Item.Parent.NamingContainer as DataGrid
//alternatively, you can search for grid in DataList controls, like this:
// yourList.FindControl("dgWarrant1") as DataGrid;

// if INCOME_TREATMENT <> R
if (e.Item.Cells[5].Text != "R")
{
    grid.Columns[4].HeaderText = "DISTRIBUTION DATE";
}
else
{
    grid.Columns[4].HeaderText = "REINVESTMENT DATE";
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But dgWarrant1 is in a DataList, so it's not accessible from code-behind. I'll update the html above. Do you know how to access dgWarrant1?

Comment: @Eera, i have edited my code. Try now to see if it helps you.

Comment: Hi @Nino. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks to your help, I can access the grid now. But the column header title didn't changed. Please help.

Comment: Try move that code into `OnRowDataBound` method instead of `ItemDataBound`

Comment: I solved it by adding another same column but different headertext and made it visible instead. But I will try to move the code to rowdatabound instead. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @Eera that's one way to do that :) Glad i could help.